# Youtube Api rate (like-dislike) post request not working

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to post rate with Youtube Data Api. I posted this link with curl : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?access_token=xxxxTOKENxxxxx&id=xxxxVIDEO_IDxxxxx&rating=dislike&key=xxxxAPI_KEYxxxxx

This request was returning 204 HTTP Code. But when I checked video, rate statistics not change. Where am i doing wrong ?

I wrote rate post request with Google PHP Library. These are my codes;

```
session_start();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client.json');
$scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit";
$client->addScope($scope);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/youtube/islem.php');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

    $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header("Location: islem.php");
} else {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

$videoID = "xxxxxxxxx";
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$result = $youtube->videos->rate($videoID, "like");

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I tried the Videos.rate [Try-It](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate#try-it) and filled in the necessary details and it worked. I was able to like a random video on Youtube by obtaining the videoId. I used the Try-it to remove the like (thumbs up) and it still works accordingly.

Try using the URI request in the Try-It generated when you press the EXECUTE button. Make sure you're logged-in to Youtube as well.

Comment: Thanks noogui. I tried on Try-It page. Yes, it worked. But when I try with my curl, it doesnt working.

Comment: And it returns 204 HTTP Code. Help page say "If successful, this method returns an HTTP 204 response code (No Content)." But it isn't successful.

Comment: i think the problem lies on your implementation of cURL since the API does work.

Comment: Thanks. I tried directly Google PHP Library. In the same it returns 204 HTTP Code. Even when i check user, the video's thumbs up icon is blue. But video's like count doesnt changing.

Comment: I am refreshing every minute :)

Comment: can you post your whole cURL statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126447/discussion-between-okancelik-and-noogui).

Comment: Thanks again noogui. I used Google PHP library. It use curl POST directly. Also if i use GET, i dont think it could not return 204 HTTP code.

So I tried directly PHP post. In the same it returns 204 HTTP Code. But counter is not changing.